# Complex INSERT and check MySql query

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to do the following with a single MySql Query.

INPUT: a list of several words to processed

I have a dictionary in table 2 and each word in it has an id. If an inputted word is in the dictionary, its dictionary id should be added to table 2 as a row. If not the word itself should be added to table 3.

OUTPUT: All the values that were added to table 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not with a single MySQL query, but you might be able to hack it together using a Trigger.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html